# How to find the current location in google maps iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, location, google-maps-sdk-ios

How can I show in google maps the current position of a user?

Do I have to read this form GPS?

Answer (score 7):

To move to your current position you have to:

```
self.googleMapsView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
```

Then you can setup a key value observer in your viewWillAppear Method and then you get your location update with the Location Manager of the GoogleMaps SDK.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Implement here to check if already KVO is implemented.
    ...
    [self.googleMapsView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:NSKeyValueObservingNew context: nil]
}
```

And then observe the property.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"] && [object isKindOfClass:[GMSMapView class]])
    {
        [self.googleMapsView animateToCameraPosition:[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:self.googleMapsView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                                                 longitude:self.googleMapsView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                                      zoom:self.googleMapsView.projection.zoom]];
    }
}
```

Do not forget to deregister your observer in the viewWillDisappear.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // Implement here if the view has registered KVO
    ...
    [self.googleMapsView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation"];
}
```

Based on Weindl answer.

Comment: Nice solution, but `GMSProjection` don't have `zoom` property

Comment: DO NOT forget to set one of these keys in your Info.plist: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Answer (score 4):

Best way and easiest way to do it using the CLLocationManagerDelegate and CLLocationManager to get your coordinates then just inject them into GMSMapView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0) zoom: 10];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.viewForMap.bounds camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    [self.viewForMap addSubview:mapView];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    [mapView animateToLocation:currentLocation.coordinate];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
... NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
```

is depreciated.

Use, as per example:

```
[self.googleMapsView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myLocation" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//In viewDidLoad
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

//Whenever you need to check location
CLLocation *myLocation = self.mapView.myLocation;
NSLog(@"%f %f",myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)updateCurrentLocation {

    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [location coordinate];
    if(noStartSet){
        startPoint = currentLocation;
        noStartSet = FALSE;
    }
    [self.mapView animateToLocation:currentLocation];    
}
```

Call this method in your `viewdidload` if you want your current location as default.